# Dash in text in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

How does one add a dash to the text in Lilypond? I would like what corresponds to `---` in LaTex and `&mdash;` in HTML. With `\addlyrics` I have tried `-`, `--` and `---`, but these attempts are not interpreted as punctuation that should not be associated with a note.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can just add `—` literally if your editor and/or input system has some way to generate it (mine works with Compose - - - for an emdash or Compose - - . for an endash) or copy and paste from some text with the right Unicode in it.

You can also write

```
\include "text-replacements.ly"
#(include-special-characters)
```

and then literally use `&mdash;` in your lyrics.

Comment: `—` generates a dash all right, but the dash is associated with a note. I do not want it to be associated with a note (my language in the question is convoluted).

Comment: Well, then don't separate it with a space from notes.  Or if you do, enclose the whole in spaces or `\markup { ... }`.  Or if you don't actually mean that you want an emdash, try "__" or "--" after the syllable in question separated with a space.  Or maybe show an image of what you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't type it directly on your keyboard, [lookup](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2014) the unicode value, and enter it as a special character:

- in decimal: `\markup{ \char #8212 }`, or
- in hexadecimal: `\markup{ \char ##x2014 }`

As seen in this page of the documentation:
[3.4.4 Special Characters - Unicode](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/special-characters#unicode)

---

### Edit:

After reading you comment to the other answer, and then reading your question again more carefully,  I see you are trying to get the symbol into lyrics.

Two dashes i.e. `--` is supposed to be used for syllable separation in lyrics, but I guess it's not as long as you want it.

### Update:

If you want to make theses inter-syllable hyphens to appear longer, still type them as `--`, but add the following override to the `\addlyrics` block:

`\override LyricHyphen.length = #2.0`